# Are values in one dataframe in bins of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named `loc_df` with two columns of bins that looks like this...

```
> loc_df

loc_x_bin        loc_y_bin      
(-20, -10]        (0, 50]           
(-140, -130]      (100, 150]        
(0,  10]          (-50, 0]
```

I have another dataframe called data that looks like this...

```
> data

  loc_x         loc_y  
   -15            25
    30            35
    5            -45
   -135          -200
```

I want to make a new boolean column in data that shows whether `loc_x` is within the values of `loc_x_bin` and `loc_y` is within `loc_y_bin` of the dataframe `loc_df`. `loc_x` and `loc_y` must be in `loc_x_bin` and `loc_y_bin` of the same row. For Example:

```
> data

 loc_x          loc_y         in_bins
  -15             25             true
   30             35             false
   5             -45             true
  -135           -200            false
   5              25             false**
```

**UPDATE**
**Although 5 is within (0,10] `loc_x_bin` and 25 is within (0, 50] `loc_y_bin`, the `loc_x_bin` and `loc_y_bin` are not in the same row so I want this to be false.

Comment: what are the objects in `loc_df`?  Are those strings? `'(-20, -10]'`

Comment: run this `type(loc_df.iloc[0, 0])` and report back what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** if you want to check that **both** `x` and `y` belong to bins from the same row in `df_loc` (or `loc_df`):

```
xstep = 10
ystep = 50

In [201]: (df.assign(bin=(pd.cut(df.loc_x, np.arange(-500, 500, xstep)).astype(str)
   .....:                 +
   .....:                 pd.cut(df.loc_y, np.arange(-500, 500, ystep)).astype(str)
   .....:                )
   .....:           )
   .....: )['bin'].isin(df_loc.sum(axis=1))
Out[201]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: bin, dtype: bool
```

Explanation:

```
In [202]: (df.assign(bin=(pd.cut(df.loc_x, np.arange(-500, 500, xstep)).astype(str)
   .....:                 +
   .....:                 pd.cut(df.loc_y, np.arange(-500, 500, ystep)).astype(str)
   .....:                )
   .....:           )
   .....: )
Out[202]:
   loc_x  loc_y                       bin
0    -15     25         (-20, -10](0, 50]
1     30     35           (20, 30](0, 50]
2      5    -45           (0, 10](-50, 0]
3   -135   -200  (-140, -130](-250, -200]
4      5     25            (0, 10](0, 50]

In [203]: df_loc.sum(axis=1)
Out[203]:
0         (-20, -10](0, 50]
1    (-140, -130](100, 150]
2           (0, 10](-50, 0]
dtype: object
```

**UPDATE:** if you want to check whether `x` belongs to `loc_x_bin` and `y` belongs to `loc_y_bin` (not necessarily from the same row in `df_loc`):

if `df_loc.dtypes` doesn't show `category` for both columns, then you may want to convert your categories to `category` dtype first:

```
df_loc.loc_x_bin = df_loc.loc_x_bin.astype('category')
df_loc.loc_y_bin = df_loc.loc_y_bin.astype('category')
```

then you can categorize your columns in the `df` "*on the fly*":

```
xstep = 10
ystep = 50

df['in_bins'] = (   (pd.cut(df.loc_x, np.arange(-500, 500, xstep)).isin(df_loc.loc_x_bin))
                    &
                    (pd.cut(df.loc_y, np.arange(-500, 500, ystep)).isin(df_loc.loc_y_bin))
                )
```

Test:

```
In [130]: df['in_bins'] = (   (pd.cut(df.loc_x, np.arange(-500, 500, xstep)).isin(df_loc.loc_x_bin))
   .....:                     &
   .....:                     (pd.cut(df.loc_y, np.arange(-500, 500, ystep)).isin(df_loc.loc_y_bin))
   .....:                 )

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
   loc_x  loc_y in_bins
0    -15     25    True
1     30     35   False
2      5    -45    True
3   -135   -200   False
```

Comment: Hmm, I am coming across a problem. I need to further restrict the criteria, so that loc_x and loc_y have to be in the x_cat bin and y_cat bin of the same row. 

So if I had:

    `loc_x = -135 and loc_y = 25` 
it should be false, but it is coming up true.

Sorry about the formatting

Comment: @Hound, can you update your question or give some examples?

Comment: Ok I edited the question. I hope it is clear now. If not please let me know, and I will try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @Hound, please check "UPDATE2"

Comment: For some reason, I can't get this to work. I get the same output as you do when I follow the 'explanation' steps, but when I run everything together all my output is 'False'. Do you have any idea why this might be?