# Pandas .cut and .isin functionality

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. First:

```
s = pd.Series( ["(-20, -10]", "(-140, -130]", "(0,  10]"], dtype = "category")
t = pd.Series( ["(0, 50]", "(100, 150]", "(-50, 0]"], dtype = "category")
df_loc = pd.DataFrame({'loc_x_bin': s, 'loc_y_bin': t })
df_loc

[out]:  
    loc_x_bin   loc_y_bin
    (-20, -10]  (0, 50]
    (-140, -130]    (100, 150]
    (0, 10] (-50, 0]
```

Second:

```
a = pd.Series( [-15, 30, 5, -135, 5, -15])
b = pd.Series( [25, 35, -45, -200, 25, 25])
data = pd.DataFrame({'loc_x': a, 'loc_y': b})
data

[out]:
     loc_x      loc_y
     -15          25
     30           35
     5           -45
    -135         -200
     5            25
    -15           25
```

I am trying to figure out if `loc_x` and `loc_y` are in `loc_x_bin` and `loc_y_bin` of the same row. See this post for more details. [Are values in one dataframe in bins of another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125507/are-values-in-one-dataframe-in-bins-of-another-dataframe). However, what I am trying to figure out now is why the 3rd and 5th row of the output below is 'False'.

```
[in]: xstep = 10
[in]: pd.cut(data.loc_x, np.arange(-500, 500, xstep)).isin(df_loc.loc_x_bin))
[out]: 
        0     True
        1    False
        2    False*
        3     True
        4    False*
        5     True
```

When I run the code below it seems to me that (0, 10] 'is in' `df_loc.loc_x_bin` because it includes a `(0,10]` bin. So why am I getting `False` in the 3rd and 5th row above?

```
[in]:
print pd.cut(data.loc_x, np.arange(-500, 500, xstep))
print df_loc.loc_x_bin

[out]:
0      (-20, -10]
1        (20, 30]
2         (0, 10]*
3    (-140, -130]
4         (0, 10]*
5      (-20, -10]

0      (-20, -10]
1    (-140, -130]
2        (0,  10]*
```

Comment: `xstep` is not defined; by guess, it seems to be `xstep=10`

Comment: No I defined `xstep`, I just forgot to include it in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the extra space in `(0,  10]` in the code above:

```
s = pd.Series( ["(-20, -10]", "(-140, -130]", "(0,  10]"], dtype = "category")
```

It should be:

```
s = pd.Series( ["(-20, -10]", "(-140, -130]", "(0, 10]"], dtype = "category")
```